# QGIS: Expression for previous value in a child layer

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to show not the newest but the previous value in a child layer with an expression? (Many child layers are joined to one parent.)

[image: example]

Comment: I have a layer with trees as parent and inspections for each tree as a child layer. If I add a second inspection values are NULL. Now I want to show the value of the first (previous) inspection in the form as a default value.